# Round statement in access to sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to duplicate a query and I'm having problems with this line. Can someone help?

```
Round([AMOUNT]*[AG_COEF],0) AS Exp,
```

gives:

```
Error at Command Line:6 Column:9
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
```

Comment: Oracle identifiers are not delimited by `[` or `]`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Round(AMOUNT*AG_COEF,0) AS Exp
```